# Does spawning a thread provide memory order guarantees on its own?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to do roughly this:

Initial thread:

- write some values to global vars (they will never be written again)

  - This could be moderately large data (arrays, strings, etc). Cannot simply be made `std::atomic<>`.
- spawn other threads

Other threads:

- read the global state
- do work, etc.

Now, I know I can pass arguments to `std::thread`, but I'm trying to understand the memory guarantees of C++ through this example.

Also, I am pretty confident that on any real-world implementation, creating a thread will cause a memory barrier ensuring that the thread can "see" everything the parent thread wrote up until that point.

But my question is: is this guaranteed by the standard?

Aside: I suppose I could add some dummy `std::atomic<int>` or so, and write to that before starting the other threads, then on the other threads, read that once on startup. I believe all the happens-before machinery would then guarantee that the previously-written global state is properly visible.

But my question is if something like that is technically required, or is thread creation enough?

Comment: *I suppose I could add some dummy `std::atomic<int>`...* You can use [`std::atomic_thread_fence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence).

Comment: @NathanOliver d'oh. removed comment. I cannot count how often you helped me here, no matter how stupid my questions are...

Comment: @idclev463035818 No worries.  It happens to us all.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thread creation is enough.  There is a synchronization point between the thread constructor and the start of the new thread per [[thread.thread.constr]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.thread.constr#6)

> *Synchronization:* The completion of the invocation of the constructor synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of `f`.

This means that all state in the thread before the new thread is spawned is visible to the spawned thread.