# read/write to variable between main thread and worker thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

In a multi-threaded C++ desktop application, if the main thread has a main loop where:

- It reads/write to a variable and then
- Invokes thread that reads/writes to that variable

Does that variable need to be synchronized if the reading/writing between the main thread and the worker thread never happens at the same time? That is the main thread reads/writes to the variable, invokes the thread(s), then waits for the threads to complete before reading/writing the variable again.

Comment: The question is what "happens at the same time" really means. The whole point of synchronization is to establish an order so that we can say that evaluations happen before or after evaluations in other threads. But starting a thread and joining a thread are synchronizing events. If that is what you are doing, then there is no problem. If "waits for the threads to complete" means something else than joining the thread the answer might be different.

Comment: What does "invokes thread" mean?

Comment: Yes, the same could be a problem if "invokes the thread(s)" doesn't actually mean starting new threads. Also, why the plural? I thought we are talking only about one spawned thread. What about data races between the multiple spawned threads?

Comment: I'm using the following parallel library to run the threads: github.com/taskflow/taskflow

Comment: @Dess You should ask a question specifically about that library and how you use it then. It is up to the implementation what guarantees it makes in which situations. You will need to read the documentation carefully.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** the answer below assumed the worker thread is created and joined by the main thread (this turned out to be false - see the update below).

---

If you are sure that the main thread is accessing the shared data before the worker thread is launched, and will access it later only when the worker thread is joined,
then you **don't** need to synchronize.

This is because **creating** a new thread (and **joining** it) is guarenteed to create a **synchronization barrier**.
It means that the changes done by the main thread will be visible to the new thread. And when the new thread is done and was joined, the changes it did will be visible to the main thread.

You can see more info in the answer to this question: [Does spawning a thread provide memory order guarantees on its own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423427/does-spawning-a-thread-provide-memory-order-guarantees-on-its-own).

---

**Update:**
As you can see in the OP's comment [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72725176/read-write-to-variable-between-main-thread-and-worker-thread/72725371?noredirect=1#comment128457872_72725371), a new threads is not actually created. A library using a thread pool is used instead. In this case the need for synchronization is dependent on the library's implementation.
If you are not sure about it - you'd better use a synchronization mechanism.

Comment: The thread(s) are not created/destroyed each time. I'm using the following parallel library to invoke the threads: https://github.com/taskflow/taskflow
That library uses a thread-pool. There is a method to invoke the library to run tasks (functions) in parallel, and another method to wait for the tasks to complete.

Comment: In this case it depends on the library implementation. If you are not sure you'd better use some synchronization mechanism. Updated my answer.